# PHP like Autoloader in Java

Tags: java, playframework, autoloader

Does the Java Interpreter support an Autoloader-Function or a possibility to extend his "Looking for a class"-function?

In PHP there is a function called spl_autoload_register (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php for details ), which forces the interpreter to execute my own callback function when he is looking for a missing class. In my callback function I can include the file with the expected class.

The background-idea is that I'd like to switch dynamically between software-layers.

For example: 
 
If class x_L2 exists in layer 2 then class x_L1 in the underlying layer 1 should be ignored. Actually I solved this issue with a general mirror class x, which have to inherit from the class in the highest available layer. But this way is error-prone when you have to maintain hundreds of classes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes are identified by their package, as classes can be identified by namespaces in PHP. 
In order to use a specific class, you can simply use a qualified name.

`public mypackage.mysubpackage.Myclass myInstanceofMyClass;`

Or you could import only the needed class :

`import mypackage.mysubpackage.Myclass;`

You cannot have a class having the same name as another class in the same package. That's a duplicate définition of a type. I am not aware of a callback function for inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using a different class loader such as `URLClassLoader`. Then, you would get your classes from this class loader with `loadClass`. Yes, it also supports local and remote resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) subclass, and use its `loadClass()` instead of the default one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to write a custom **class loader** ?

IBM has [good documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142/html/id1100.html) on that to help you on that.